# Raspberry: Qt issue connecting device because SSH client-server capabilities don't match

Tags: c++, qt, ssh

I'm trying to launch an application in C++ done with QtCreator:
[image]
This is the error:
[image]
I can see the error if I try to test the connection with created device or calling run on QtCreator.
I don't have any idea how to align capabilities.
Can someone tell me which file I have to modify to fix the issue?
I found some info about "sshd_config" file but I didn't find a way to solve.

I tried to modify the file as suggested, thanks by the way, but with the change the ssh doesn't start at all.

[image]

So, I'm sorry for the question but, there is a position defined where I can/should place the suggested line? 
This is my file
[image]
[image]

[image]

I tried at the begin, at bottom, in the middle, nothing the connection was refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved adding this string and as I was not sure where apply it, I would like to show exactly which line was added:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The client is offering a list of broken ciphers. You should consider updating the Qt Craetor or whatever is this software using to connect to the remote device.

The other possibility is to allow these ciphers on the server (device). Add

```
Ciphers +aes128-cbc
```

to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart the `sshd` service. If it will not work, use for example this list:

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc
```

and restart the sshd service on the device.

Comment: I solved! Thanks for hints, I found probably the small mistake, you wrote "aes128-crt" instead of "aes128-ctr".